# How to display float left on top of position absolute (z-index not working)

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that has two children.
One child is `stone-group-handle` that uses `float:left` the other is `stone-wrap` that uses `position:relative` and `position:absolute` to display it's child on `0, 0`.

I need `stone-group-handle` to show up on top left upfront and `stone-wrap` to show at top left behind `stone-group-handle`.

How can I make `stone-group-handle` show on top?

http://codepen.io/eguneys/pen/XbxRJE

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
}
.stone-group-handle {
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1em;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.stone-group-handle:hover {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.stone-group {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.stones-wrap {
  height: 50px;
  width: 123px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.stone {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  background: black;
}
.stone2 {
  left: 43px;
}
.stone3 {
  left: 84px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stone-group">
  <div class="stone-group-handle">
    30
  </div>
  <div class="stones-wrap">
    <div class="stone">
    </div>
    <div class="stone stone2">
    </div>
    <div class="stone stone3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited you question to include the Code Pen code in your actual question. In future please ensure you include all the relevant code in the question itself as it is possible that the link may die leaving no working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you set `position: relative;` on `.stone-group-handle` as well as `z-index: 1;`. By default `position` is set to `static` and `z-index` does not have any effect on `static` elements.

> **'z-index'**
>
> Applies to:   positioned elements

(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index)

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
}
.stone-group-handle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1em;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.stone-group-handle:hover {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.stone-group {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.stones-wrap {
  height: 50px;
  width: 123px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.stone {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  background: black;
}
.stone2 {
  left: 43px;
}
.stone3 {
  left: 84px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stone-group">
  <div class="stone-group-handle">
    30
  </div>
  <div class="stones-wrap">
    <div class="stone">
    </div>
    <div class="stone stone2">
    </div>
    <div class="stone stone3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```